# Seaborn.despine() negates the effect of moving the y-axis to the right hand side of the figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

There are plenty of examples out there on creating a plot with two or more y-axes, but moving a singular y-axis to the right hand side of the plot is a bit more tricky it seems.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

values = np.random.randint(1,20,100)

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
# sns.despine(offset=10) <- problem here...

ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
sns.distplot(values)
```

The snippet above creates a plot with the ticks on the right, however if you want to despine the plot (uncomment the indicated line) it looks like this:

[image]

Side question: The motivation behind the axis on the right is because I am plotting this together with another plot side by side and I would like the y-axes to be on either side of the subplots, rather than in between them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[seaborn's `despine` has arguments](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.despine.html) to let you choose which of the spine to hide (by default, everything but the left one).

> top, right, left, bottom : boolean, optional
>
> If True, remove that spine.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

values = np.random.randint(1,20,100)

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
sns.despine(offset=10, left=True, right=False)  # <-- only show the right spine
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')  # <--- I also edited this line to have tick marks only on the right
sns.distplot(values)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to control this separately for each subplot though? As I wrote in the bottom of the question, I have 2 distplots side by side, I want one of them to have the left spine and the other to have the right spine.

Comment: Sure, simply use the `ax=<ref to your subplot>` argument to each call to `despine`